# Method to Embed Tweet in Status Update

Tags: tweepy

Is there a method to embed a tweet in a status update, using tweepy?

I've seen a few bots posting status updates with embedded tweets, so I'm confident it's possible through the API but I've been unable to find a method for doing so in the tweepy documentation or searches.

*Note: This is my first post here, although I've been using stackoverflow for a while now. I haven't really had to make a post until now because I'm almost always able to find an answer to my questions, which is a compliment to the great community here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include the url of the other tweet in your tweet. The twitter web UI just renders it embeded in the main tweet.

Comment: That worked. That was much easier than I thought it would be haha... Thank you!